# Задний фон dropdown при использовании AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

При добавлении бэкграунда в котором указан радиус, видно как идет просвет под список а именно видно черный фон. Я использую `AutoCompleteTextView` как PainText + выпадающий список.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

theme.xml

```
<stryle>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="DropDownListViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/drawable_spinner_item_round</item>
</style>
<style name="DropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

drawable_spinner_item_round.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/item_dropdown"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp" />

    <size
        android:height="60dp"
        android:width="270dp" />
</shape>
```

fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_spinner_grey"
        android:maxLines="1"


        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/tw_your_country"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_arrow_country"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:tag="arrow_down"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
        android:onClick="click_btn_arrow_country"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

и сам код

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayCountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Location_Fragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country));



ArrayAdapter<String> arrayCity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Location_Fragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city));



spinner_country = (AutoCompleteTextView) Location_Fragment.this.findViewById(R.id.spinner_country);
spinner_country.setAdapter(arrayCountry);
spinner_city = (AutoCompleteTextView) Location_Fragment.this.findViewById(R.id.spinner_city);
spinner_city.setAdapter(arrayCity);
```

Буду благодарен за помощь. И еще может если кто-то знает, можно ли как-то убрать появление анимации этого списка, то есть что-бы он сразу создался а не всплывал?

Answer (score 0):

решение проблемы

```
        textView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_item_round));
```